# 2nd order DE, controller and feedback loop, modeling cruise control.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

controller:

$\dfrac Ks$

car dynamics:

$\dfrac 1M / (s + \dfrac DM)$

closed loop response block diagram:

$\dfrac KM / (s^2 + \dfrac DM s + \dfrac KM)$

2nd order DE for the closed loop system:

$y''(t) + \dfrac DM y'(t) + \dfrac KMy(t) = \dfrac KM v_d(t)$

K is the controller gain

$v_d(t)$ is the input function

$y(t)$ is the output velocity

$D = 100kg/s$

$M = 1,000kg$

QUESTION 1:

Solve the DE for $y(t)$ with the IC's $y(0) = 20.8m/s$ and $y'(0) = 0$ if the input is a step function scaled by the desired velocity $V_o$.

$v_d(t) = V_ou(t)$

Assume the desired velocity $V_o = 27.8m/s$

QUESTION 2:

Find the optimal controller gain $K$ to give the desired response without a large overshoot or a slow response time.

SO FAR I've Laplaced the entire equation, solving for $Y(s)$ I have:

$Y(s) = [ (KV_o/Ms) + y'(0) + sy(0) + (D/M)y(0) ] / [ s^2 + (D/M)s + (K/M) ]$

Comment: I'm Laplace-ing the entire equation in order to solve for Y(s).  Thereby consolidating all of the $s$ terms on the RHS.  And I'm getting a massive fraction on the RHS.  With $K$ variables.  If in fact I'm on the right track, my problem will be inverse Laplace-ing the RHS fraction.

Comment: You have to split the fraction. You know about partial fraction decomposition, right?

Comment: $A/1000s + B/(s + 1/10s + K/100)$?  So I'm on the right track?

Comment: Yes, you are, but don't forget the factor you already had in the beginning. Why don't you perform an Euclidean division first, before going on to partial fractions.

Comment: Hmm, never heard of that.  Googling it.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Write the diff equation as

$$M y'' +D y' + K y=k V_0 u(t)$$

Laplace transforming the equation, where

$$\hat{y}(s) = \int_0^{\infty} dt \, y(t) \, e^{-s t}$$

is the Laplace transform of the solution, we get

$$(M s^2+D s+K) \hat{y}(s) - (M s+d) y(0) - M y'(0) = \frac{K V_0}{s}$$

Solving for $\hat{y}(s)$, and applying the initial conditions, we get

$$\hat{y}(s) = \frac{(M s+D) v_0}{M s^2+D s+K} + \frac{K V_0}{s (M s^2+D s+K)}$$

I invert by using residues, i.e.,

$$y(t) = V_0+\left [\frac{(M s_++D) v_0}{2 M s_++D} + \frac{K V_0}{s_+ (2 M s_++D)}\right ] e^{s_+ t} +  \left [\frac{(M s_-+D) v_0}{2 M s_-+D} + \frac{K V_0}{s_- (2 M s_-+D)}\right ] e^{s_- t} $$

where

$$s_{\pm} = -\frac{D}{2 M} \pm \frac{\sqrt{D^2-4 K M}}{2 M}$$

So you are given everything but $K$, which you must find by "optimizing" response time to get to the desired speed $V_0$.  It seems to me that the optimum which avoids both excessive delay and oscillations would be achieved when

$$D^2-4 K M = 0$$

(which would require a completely different solution ).

Comment: Thanks Ron.  Some of that is way over my head as of yet.  The residues for example.  Never heard of that.  Our professor barely touched on these ideas and then threw us in the deep end.

Comment: @Eli: I understand, so you're left with a partial fraction decomposition, etc.  the algebra gets messy no matter what you do, but residues, while getting you to the same place, allow a much more general framework that does not depend on tables.  The important thing to note is that, at pole $s_0$, the residue of $p(s)/q(s)$ at that pole is $$\frac{p(s_0)}{q'(s_0)}$$

Comment: Is there any way you could break it down a little more using tables instead of residues?  This is a 1st or 2nd year engineering class.  I can do Laplace transforming and inverse transforming no problema, given they are in table form or at least can be broken down to a point where you can use the table.  I mean, our prof has only gone over simple partial frac decomp!  Like factoring a 2nd order poly in the denom, and that's it.  Once I've Laplaced this 2nd order equation all hell breaks loose and I just don't know what to do with it.  I would greatly appreciate it man.

Comment: Or is there another way using direct integration?